# Play Scala Oauth Provider Error

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework

I am building a Play Scala project and need an authentication for the apps.
I am using this one : https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider as the Oauth Provider libs.
I have implement everything based on the docs. But when implement the Auth on the controller below :

```
object Token extends MainController with OAuth2Provider {
def accessToken = Action.async { implicit request =>
issueAccessToken(new MyDataHandler()
}
```

And here my router :

```
GET     /test                           controllers.Token.test
POST    /token                          controllers.Token.accessToken
```

When I access localhost/token, i got this error :
[image]

And here the error from console :

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface play.api.mvc.Headers, but class was expected]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface play.api.mvc.Headers, but class was expected
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:523) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:129) ~[play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface play.api.mvc.Headers, but class was expected
        at scalaoauth2.provider.OAuth2BaseProvider$class.play2oauthRequest(OAuth2Provider.scala:24) ~[play2-oauth2-provider_2.10-0.15.1.jar:0.15.1]
        at controllers.Token$.play2oauthRequest(Token.scala:14) ~[na:na]
        at scalaoauth2.provider.OAuth2Provider$class.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Provider.scala:138) ~[play2-oauth2-provider_2.10-0.15.1.jar:0.15.1]
        at controllers.Token$.issueAccessToken(Token.scala:14) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.Token$$anonfun$accessToken$1.apply(Token.scala:25) ~[na:na]
```

I have implement everything what does docs said. Sorry I am actually new on Scala and on the Play it self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you use Play and scala-oauth2-provider version?

The error looks Play version is different.
If you use Play 2.3, you should use 0.14.0 in scala-oauth2-provider.

See readme.

Comment: Hi @tsuyoshi : Thanks for your help. It fixed now.
Actually, I was download the latest Play Framework (I guess it was 2.4) and using simple-rest template, And didn't know that the template using 2.3